# Error There was a problem opening the stream. When using Bigquery Storage Write COMMITED Type

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'trying to use the API Bigquery Storage with python https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#overview_of_the

Since I need the type COMMITED and not PENDING, I've changed a little bit from the example.
The problema is that when I get to `response_future_1 = append_rows_stream.send(request)` I get this error

```
"There was a problem opening the stream. "
"Try turning on DEBUG level logs to see the error."
```

I turn on all my DEBUG logs and didn't get any answer.

Here is my code:

```py
def create_row_data(**data):
    row = something_stream_pb2.SomethingStream()
    row.one = data.get('one')
    row.two = data.get('two')
    row.three = data.get('three')
    return row.SerializeToString()


def create_bigquery_storage_client(google_credentials):
    return bigquery_storage_v1.client.BigQueryWriteClient(
        credentials=google_credentials
    )


class GcpBigqueryStorageService(object):

    def __init__(self, google_credentials, gcp_config):
        self.client = create_bigquery_storage_client(google_credentials)
        self.config = gcp_config

    def append_rows_pending(self, ctx, project_id: str, dataset_id: str, table_id: str, data: [dict]):

        """Create a write stream, write some sample data, and commit the stream."""
        # write_client = self.client
        parent = self.client.table_path(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
        write_stream = types.WriteStream()

        # When creating the stream, choose the type. Use the PENDING type to wait
        # until the stream is committed before it is visible. See:
        # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.WriteStream.Type
        write_stream.type_ = types.WriteStream.Type.COMMITTED
        write_stream = self.client.create_write_stream(
            parent=parent, write_stream=write_stream
        )
        stream_name = write_stream.name

        # Create a template with fields needed for the first request.
        request_template = types.AppendRowsRequest()

        # The initial request must contain the stream name.
        request_template.write_stream = stream_name

        # So that BigQuery knows how to parse the serialized_rows, generate a
        # protocol buffer representation of your message descriptor.
        proto_schema = types.ProtoSchema()
        proto_descriptor = descriptor_pb2.DescriptorProto()
        something_stream_pb2.SomethingStream.DESCRIPTOR.CopyToProto(proto_descriptor)
        proto_schema.proto_descriptor = proto_descriptor
        proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
        proto_data.writer_schema = proto_schema
        request_template.proto_rows = proto_data

        # Some stream types support an unbounded number of requests. Construct an
        # AppendRowsStream to send an arbitrary number of requests to a stream.
        append_rows_stream = writer.AppendRowsStream(self.client, request_template)

        # Create a batch of row data by appending proto2 serialized bytes to the
        # serialized_rows repeated field.
        proto_rows = types.ProtoRows()
        for row in data:
            proto_rows.serialized_rows.append(create_row_data(**row))

        # Set an offset to allow resuming this stream if the connection breaks.
        # Keep track of which requests the server has acknowledged and resume the
        # stream at the first non-acknowledged message. If the server has already
        # processed a message with that offset, it will return an ALREADY_EXISTS
        # error, which can be safely ignored.
        #
        # The first request must always have an offset of 0.
        request = types.AppendRowsRequest()
        # request.offset = 0
        proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
        proto_data.rows = proto_rows
        request.proto_rows = proto_data

        response_future_1 = append_rows_stream.send(request)

        logger.info(ctx, f'Result {response_future_1.result()}')

        append_rows_stream.close()
```

Edit1:

My something_stream.proto is written like this:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message SomethingStream {
  string one = 1;
  string two = 2;
  string three = 3;
}
```

and is build like this

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: app/application/presentation/protobuff/something_stream.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n=app/application/presentation/protobuff/something_stream.proto\":\n\x0fSomethingStream\x12\x0b\n\x03one\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0b\n\x03two\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x05three\x18\x03 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')



_SOMETHINGSTREAM = DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['SomethingStream']
SomethingStream = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('SomethingStream', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _SOMETHINGSTREAM,
  '__module__' : 'app.application.presentation.protobuff.something_stream_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:SomethingStream)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(SomethingStream)

if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  _SOMETHINGSTREAM._serialized_start=65
  _SOMETHINGSTREAM._serialized_end=123
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

And my data is

```py
{
 'one': 'something',
 'two': 'something',
 'three': 'something'
}
```

Comment: Please share your `something_stream_pb2` script and your data dictionary. Tried it on our end and COMMITTED type seems to work.

Comment: @AnjelaB , tkz for your reply. I just updated the question with the information you asked.

Comment: we have tried running your script and it seems to work. We noticed though that the build your .proto produced was different to ours. We used this [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers) to build your .proto, let us know if this changes your build.

Comment: Got the same message, in my case, when I added **logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)** it showed the reason was the write schema doesn't match the table schema, ... because I created the table with empty schema.

Answer (score 1):

*As I spent a few days working on a POC to use Python Client for BigQuery Storage API, I found this StackOverflow question and thought I should share what I did and answer this question.*

I made a few changes in OP's files, let me walk through what I did:

Proto file remains the same.

I used `protoc` to generate a Python file called `something_stream_pb2.py`:

1. Installed `protoc` using `sudo apt install protobuf-compiler` on Ubuntu.
2. Generate the python file `protoc -I=. --python_out=. something_stream.proto`

The generated file:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: something_stream.proto

from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='something_stream.proto',
  package='',
  syntax='proto3',
  serialized_options=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_pb=b'\n\x16something_stream.proto\":\n\x0fSomethingStream\x12\x0b\n\x03one\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0b\n\x03two\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x05three\x18\x03 \x01(\tb\x06proto3'
)




_SOMETHINGSTREAM = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='SomethingStream',
  full_name='SomethingStream',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='one', full_name='SomethingStream.one', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='two', full_name='SomethingStream.two', index=1,
      number=2, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='three', full_name='SomethingStream.three', index=2,
      number=3, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=26,
  serialized_end=84,
)

DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['SomethingStream'] = _SOMETHINGSTREAM
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

SomethingStream = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('SomethingStream', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _SOMETHINGSTREAM,
  '__module__' : 'something_stream_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:SomethingStream)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(SomethingStream)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

Created a test table in BigQuery following the data types in the proto file:

[image]

Then I created a `run.py` file to run it - I reused most of the code from the OP:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1 import types
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1 import writer
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
import logging
import something_stream_pb2


def create_row_data(data):
    row = something_stream_pb2.SomethingStream()
    row.one = data.get("one")
    row.two = data.get("two")
    row.three = data.get("three")
    return row.SerializeToString()


class GcpBigqueryStorageService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Create a write stream, write some sample data, and commit the stream."""
        self.client = bigquery_storage_v1.BigQueryWriteClient()

    def append_rows_pending(
        self, project_id: str, dataset_id: str, table_id: str, data: dict
    ):

        # write_client = self.client
        parent = self.client.table_path(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
        write_stream = types.WriteStream()

        # When creating the stream, choose the type. Use the PENDING type to wait
        # until the stream is committed before it is visible. See:
        # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.WriteStream.Type
        write_stream.type_ = types.WriteStream.Type.COMMITTED
        write_stream = self.client.create_write_stream(
            parent=parent, write_stream=write_stream
        )
        stream_name = write_stream.name

        # Create a template with fields needed for the first request.
        request_template = types.AppendRowsRequest()

        # The initial request must contain the stream name.
        request_template.write_stream = stream_name

        # So that BigQuery knows how to parse the serialized_rows, generate a
        # protocol buffer representation of your message descriptor.
        proto_schema = types.ProtoSchema()
        proto_descriptor = descriptor_pb2.DescriptorProto()
        something_stream_pb2.SomethingStream.DESCRIPTOR.CopyToProto(proto_descriptor)
        proto_schema.proto_descriptor = proto_descriptor
        proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
        proto_data.writer_schema = proto_schema
        request_template.proto_rows = proto_data

        # Some stream types support an unbounded number of requests. Construct an
        # AppendRowsStream to send an arbitrary number of requests to a stream.
        append_rows_stream = writer.AppendRowsStream(self.client, request_template)

        # Create a batch of row data by appending proto2 serialized bytes to the
        # serialized_rows repeated field.
        proto_rows = types.ProtoRows()
        for row in data:
            proto_rows.serialized_rows.append(create_row_data(row))

        # Set an offset to allow resuming this stream if the connection breaks.
        # Keep track of which requests the server has acknowledged and resume the
        # stream at the first non-acknowledged message. If the server has already
        # processed a message with that offset, it will return an ALREADY_EXISTS
        # error, which can be safely ignored.
        #
        # The first request must always have an offset of 0.
        request = types.AppendRowsRequest()
        # request.offset = 0
        proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
        proto_data.rows = proto_rows
        request.proto_rows = proto_data

        response_future_1 = append_rows_stream.send(request)

        logger.info(f"Result {response_future_1.result()}")

        append_rows_stream.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger("example_logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    service = GcpBigqueryStorageService()
    data = [{"one": "something", "two": "something", "three": "something"}]
    service.append_rows_pending("your-project-id", "test_dataset", "test", data=data)
```

After running it, the data was inserted to BigQuery:

[image]

I mostly followed the sample code from [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage/blob/main/samples/snippets/append_rows_proto2.py).

**Findings:**

1. There may be an issue in some of the earlier versions of this Python Client. The version(2.13.2) I used works well.
2. There may be a mismatch of data types among Python, proto and BigQuery. In my case, I had an issue with `uint64`, I had to switch to `int64` in proto file to make it work. You may want to double-check the data types.

I hope this helps anybody who is stuck on this.